# A movie with the same concept of The Thing and Leviathan

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I saw a new trailer a couple of months ago. It was a sci-fi/horror film with an alien life-form host on people which started transforming into a gory status/shape. Yes, it sounds like the movie "*The Thing*",  but it was a new film coming out this year or next year. I wonder which film it is.

Comment: It's not the prequel/ remake of *The Thing* that came out in the last year or two, is it?

Comment: Could you please describe more of what happened in the trailer? If it was a month ago it should be somewhat still fresh in your mind.

Answer (score 6):

At the risk of stating the obvious, could you be thinking of The Thing (2012)?

[image]

There's a NSFW (violence/gore) trailer available on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amARolcCW7c).

Comment: If he is, indeed, right about it coming out this year or next, a 2012 film will probably not match up. There goes my suggestion of *Last Winter*...

Comment: @seadduggan - Some films come out in different territories in different years. Also, he may simply be mistaken. The description fits nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Could it possibly be [*Harbinger Down*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbinger_Down)?

> The plot of the film follows a group of graduate students aboard the
>   titular fishing trawler Harbinger, who are studying the effects of
>   global warming on a pod of Orcas in the Bering Sea. When the ship's
>   crew discover the wreckage of Soviet era spacecraft, they are attacked
>   by shapeshifting alien monsters.

Comment: I'm unsure why this (perfectly good answer) has attracted a downvote :-(